# After login with auth0 I need the JWT from a AMP page

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am using AMP google pages technology. For logging in, I am using auth0.

What I need to do is after logging I need to access the JWT that comes from the current login and extract an attribute from the payload.

The issue here, at least what I understand, the JWT is "inside" the AMP environment so it is not possible to stract.